# Angular prevent click event on one field within card

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of cards that looks somewhat like [image: this]

And when clicked on they're meant to go to another page. I am accomplishing this by using a `(click)` event. Like `(click)="goToFunction()"` on the containing HTML.

```
<div (click)="goToFunction()">
  <p>Words here</p>
  <select></select>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this is also causing the click to happen on the dropdown element. Is there a way to omit the dropdown from this click?

I have tried attaching a click event to the dropdown and in that event having a `event.stopPropagation()` in it. I also attempted a `return false`. Neither of these worked.

Any ideas? I don't really want to have a 'click here' link on the cards to get around this.

Comment: Could you please drop your code into a standalone IDE (like stackblitz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the target of the event, and check if it's the select box or not.

Note that there are a lot of properties on the event target, and sometimes they differ between browsers.  There may be a more appropriate property other than the `tagName` depending on your final use case.

See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5nqk1g

```html
<div (click)="goToFunction($event)">
  <p>Words here</p>
  <select></select>
</div>
```

```js
goToFunction(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('click event', event, event.target);
    // this is an example of using the target.tagName, but check the log for event.target and maybe there is something more appropriate for your use case
    if ((<any>event.target).tagName === "SELECT") {
      // do nothing, its the select
      console.log("You DID click the select")

    } else {
      console.log("You didn't click the select")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a directive to stop event propagation

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[stop-event-propagation]"
})
export class StopEventPropagation
{
    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

In Html add directive attribute name

```
<div (click)="goToFunction()">
      <h1>Words here</h1>
      <h2>Words here</h2>    
      <select  stop-event-propagation>
        <option>Test</option>
      </select>
  <h3>Words here</h3>
  <h4>Words here</h4>
</div>
```

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxa1sv)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you enclose the drop-down in it's own container that doesn't have the route binding or the other way around?

```html
<div>
  <div (click)="goToFunction()">
    <p>Words here</p>
    ...
  </div>
  <select></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it has to be inside that div because if they click outside of the dropdown it's supposed to go to that link. It's also a part of a larger form and there is more code making things work

Answer (score -1):

yes he could do that (Michael D solution)or use an a tag with routerLink, so that no function binding is needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider giving a code example.